# Could not find artifact org.glassfish.jaxb:jaxb-runtime:jar:2.3.3-b02-jbossorg-2 in jakarta.oss.sonatype.org

Tags: hibernate, jakarta-ee, jaxb, java-17

I am seeing this error while in my code after migrating to JDK 17.

Downloading from jakarta.oss.sonatype.org: https://jakarta.oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/org/glassfish/jaxb/jaxb-runtime/2.3.3-b02-jbossorg-2/jaxb-runtime-2.3.3-b02-jbossorg-2.pom
Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/glassfish/jaxb/jaxb-runtime/2.3.3-b02-jbossorg-2/jaxb-runtime-2.3.3-b02-jbossorg-2.pom
[WARNING] The POM for org.glassfish.jaxb:jaxb-runtime:jar:2.3.3-b02-jbossorg-2 is missing, no dependency information available

[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project test web: Could not resolve dependencies for project XXXXXXXXX:war:1.0: **Could not find artifact org.glassfish.jaxb:jaxb-runtime:jar:2.3.3-b02-jbossorg-2**
in jakarta.oss.sonatype.org (https://jakarta.oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases) -

This is what I have in the pom.xml

```
<repository>     
  <id>jakarta.oss.sonatype.org</id>      
  <name>Jakarta OSS Sonatype releases</name>            <url>https://jakarta.oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases</url> 
</repository>
```

The URL https://jakarta.oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases does have the repository in a slightly different path

https://jakarta.oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/org/glassfish/jaxb/jaxb-runtime/2.3.3-b02/

Any ideas on how to fix this ?

Comment: Couldn't you get the latest release of jaxb-runtime (2.3.9) ?